# Django 1.8: Issue with using cleaned_data

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am having a weird issue. I am using a Select field that is bound with data returned from Model. It is defined as:

```
choices = Subscription.objects.filter(is_full_version=False)
subscription_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=choices)
```

`request.POST` returns the `id` from `value` attribute of option but when I call:
`form.cleaned_data.get('subscription_id')` it rather returns:

`'subscription_id': <Subscription: Gold>`

`Gold` is text rather Id.

`request.POST` rather returns what I want:
`subscription_id': [u'3']`

What's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch the value for a `ModelChoiceField` from the `cleaned_data`, you get the model instance, not the id.

It's easy to get the primary key from the instance. Just remember to handle `None`.

```
subscription = form.cleaned_data.get('subscription_id')
if subscription is not None:
    subscription_id = subscription.pk
```